# how to delete records by click on delete button in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am writing a extjs program for deleting the records but once i am using the plugin for row editing the page is not showing the result. so how to write the code for delete the records by click on delete button in extjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the answers in the following link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451898/extjs-grid-delete-row-getting-selected-row
```

Hope it helps you.